# Raspberry btmon --server parameter

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am looking for a solution to monitor BLE devices near my raspberry with their RSSI value. So far I am done with monitoring, all devices and the current rssi value is displayed on screen, but I would like to

- store the values in a database or
- send them to RabbitMQ (either solution is fine).

I am using **btmon** for monitoring which has a switch "`-s`" or "`--server`". Unfortunately I did not find any useful documentation on it (might be my fault). I thought this might start monitoring in a way that I can query it from another application. Any clue?

The other solution could be `node.js/noble`, but noble installation always fails.

Answer (score 0):

Well, btmon could not be my solution as device discovery needs to be triggered with `hcitool lescan` which does not have a recurrence parameter (only `hcitool scan` has). The solution finally was `node.js/noble`. The installation failed, because I tried to do it with the latest version of noble.js. Going back to 10.x solved the problem.